# Xdamage: get event on window content changes

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, xorg

I am a beginner in xlib and I want to catch event on window content changes. For examples if some region changed. I've read that I need to use Xdamage for that and this is my code

```
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    XWindowAttributes attributes = {0};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &attributes);
    int width, height;
    width = attributes.width;
    height = attributes.height;
    //XDAMAGE INIT
    int damage_event, damage_error, test;
    test = XDamageQueryExtension(display, &damage_event, &damage_error);
    Damage damage = XDamageCreate(display, root, XDamageReportNonEmpty);
    while (true){
        XEvent event;
        XNextEvent(display,&event);
        //HERE I GET EVENT
        XDamageSubtract(display,damage,None,None);
    }
    XCloseDisplay(display);
```

So, I have a working example in which I can get event and its type.The types, as I understand are xlib types - https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/types.html. But how can I find out from event that window was changed.

Comment: you want to check the return value of `XDamageQueryExtension`. It is not guaranteed that the extension is actually loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are actually receiving are `DamageNotify` events in your normal event loop that look like so:

```
typedef struct {
   int type;            /* event base */
   unsigned long serial;
   Bool send_event;
   Display *display;
   Drawable drawable;
   Damage damage;
   int level;
   Bool more;           /* more events will be delivered immediately */
   Time timestamp;
   XRectangle area;
   XRectangle geometry;
} XDamageNotifyEvent;
```

according to the documentation from https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/damageproto/damageproto.txt

The `area` member reports the damaged rectangular area as an XRectangle.

The `drawable` member normally reports the window that was damaged.

Note `XNextEvent` will always return an `XEvent` That is the *static* type returned by the function. It also has a *dynamic* type that depends on the `ev->type` member. - Check its `type` field to find out if you may cast it to an `XDamageEvent`:

```
XEvent ev;

/* We might need a pointer to an XDamageEvent... */
XDamageNotifyEvent *dev;

while (1) {
   XNextEvent(display,&ev);
   switch (ev.type){
      ...
      case DamageNotify:
         dev = (XDamageNotifyEvent*)&ev; /* if type matches, cast to XDamageNotify  event */
         printf ("Damage notification in window %d\n", dev->drawable);
         printf ("Rectangle x=%d, y=%d, w=%d, h=%d\n",
                 dev->area.x, dev->area.y, 
                 dev->area.width, dev->area.height);
         break;
      ...
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you explain how I can get `XDamageNotifyEvent` instead of `XEvent`?

Comment: Note an XEvent has both a *static* (its "C" type) and a *dynamic* type. `XNextEvnet` returns an `XEvent` that might actually be an `XDamage` event if its dynamic type says so. Example added to answer.

Comment: I am a java developer. If it is not difficult for you, can you show how to get `XDamageNotifyEvent`?

Comment: You may already get one, but simply don't detect it. See code example in answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed. But what should I #include to solve `XDamageEvent was not declared in this scope`? Now I have `#include <X11/extensions/Xdamage.h>#include <X11/Xlib.h>#include <X11/Xutil.h>`

Comment: It actually seems to be `XDamageNotifyEvent` - Sorry, my bad. Don't have a Linux box at hand at the moment. Corrected above

Comment: `area` always gives me the full window size, not the rect that actually changed. Is there any way to extract that information (from a XserverRegion if necessary)?

Comment: `area` will grow over time if you don't tell the system you've fixed it with XDamageSubtract. After a few window affecting actions, `area` will be the full window. Other than that, there are a lot of actions that look "small", but actually "damage" the whole window.

Answer (score 3):

Late, but for anyone looking for the area that actually changed (ev->area are the window coordinates and size, for me at least):

```
auto ev = (XDamageNotifyEvent*)e;
auto region = XFixesCreateRegion(display, null, 0);
XDamageSubtract(display, ev->damage, None, region);
int count;
auto area = XFixesFetchRegion(display, region, &count);
if(area){
    for(int i; i < count; i++){
        auto rect = area[i];
        // do something with rect
    }
    XFree(area);
}
XFixesDestroyRegion(display, region);
```

Comment: a few words of warning: both `XFixesFetchRegion` and `XDamageDestroy` can throw errors even if you did nothing wrong, standard practice it seems is to ignore them (xcompmgr src is my reference). if anyone has an explanation why this is the case it would be appreciated, i cant find one

Comment: never had a problem with that, but I also only call the above code during a XDamageNotifyEvent and don't keep anything around after that. maybe that's why.

Comment: the errors only appear if you're monitoring them from X, here are the lines in xcomp and picom (note the explicit ignore): https://github.com/freedesktop/xcompmgr/blob/master/xcompmgr.c#L1150 , https://github.com/yshui/picom/blob/next/src/event.c#L585 . might be something specific to compositor stuff where you are interfacing with a lot of windows